# c++ cross initialization jump to case label when initializing a float array

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, ubuntu, g++

I have 3 classes M , L , P , each have its own .header and .cpp for encapsulation practice i have put relevant functions and attributes respectively in each .header and .cpp

i have this function `float L::calculate(arg,arg,arg,arg)`here that is in L.cpp , its just a fixed formula which arguments taken from the class itselfs . But i have a another class P

In P.cpp , i have get/set of the calculate function of L class . In class P i also have contructors , 1 default and 1 that takes in args (i initialize L in both constructors as well)

then in my class M where all the implementaion comes together .

i am trying to  create a float array like this :

```
float calculateThis[size]; // the size is fixed at 50.
```

then in a for loop where x is less than size

i did this :

```
calculateThis[x] = newL[x].caculate(args,args,args,args);
newP.setCalculate(calculateThis[x]);
++x;
```

I have also declare on top

```
L newL[size]; //Used for some other methods that i have wrote to get inputs   and save it .
P newP[size];
```

when i compile i get this error :

```
  crosses initialization of ‘float calculateThis[size]’
   float calculateThis[size];
```

Basically i am trying to save the calcuated function that returns a float into a float array

**EDIT:**

```
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: // 1st Choice.
    while(entry<size)
    {
      //getting user input and saving it by newL.set / newP.set     
    };
    break;

    case 2:
    float calculateThis[size]; // the size is fixed at 50.
  for(x=0,x<size)
  {       calculateThis[x] = newL[x].caculate(newL.get(),newL.get(),newL.get(),newL.get());
          newP.setCalculate(calculateThis[x]);
           ++x;
  }
    break;

    default:break;  
    }
```

Comment: "_It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps from a point where a local variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has POD type (3.9) and is declared without an initializer._" Show us more of your code. It's probably a `case` statement that you messed up.

Comment: check edits @GillBates , i have add in some codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets to indicate that this is local scope for `calculateThis`:

```
    case 2:
    {
      float calculateThis[size]; // the size is fixed at 50.
      for(x=0,x<size)
      {       
        calculateThis[x] = newL[x].caculate(newL.get(),newL.get(),newL.get(),newL.get());
          newP.setCalculate(calculateThis[x]);
           ++x;
      }
     }break;
```